# Add button in visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce, salesforcedx, visualforce-component

I create visualforce email template  when i add the code for button

```
<apex:form>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!send}" value="Send my email" id="theButton"/>
    </apex:form>
```

its show me error ***"messaging:emailTemplate cannot contain apex:form."***
so for this i create visaulforce component  and add this component in to visualforce email template
`<c:createlead/>`  and add button here in component. The component save successfully  but still  visualfroce email template give same error.How to solve this ??

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Salesforce forms in an email. You would want to use something like [Web 2 Any](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000DlGucUAF) or something else (please do research before making any purchasing decisions), or you can set up a [Salesforce Site](https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=sf.sites_creating_and_editing_sites.htm&type=5) and host your Visualforce page there; the email would contain a link to the Site where your subscribers can securely enter their information.